# Confusions about the definitions of "draw on"

Tags: idiom-requests, idiom-meaning

The idiom **draw on** as I know has many definitions. Two of which are *to approach* and *to pass gradually*

This can be very confusing because the same phrase has two opposite meanings.

Here's an example where confusion may come up:

> The storm lessened as the night drew on. (From The Free Dictionary)

Is it saying that the night is approaching or passing?

For those who saying it has to be approach, here is a pic of the definition from the free dict. :
[image]

Comment: As the night progressed.

Comment: Quite right; it's ambiguous. I'd certainly go with the _approaching_ sense for 'The storm lessened as night drew on' but plump for the _passing gradually, approaching an end_ sense for 'The storm lessened as the night drew on'.

Answer (score 1):

I see the distinction that Edwin Ashworth (in a comment above) advocates between

> The storm lessened as night [that is, darkness] drew on.

which he sees as having the sense "as night approached," and

> The storm lessened as the night [that is, the hours of darkness] drew on.

which he sees as tending to mean "as the hours of the night gradually passed by."

Still, that distinction is rather fine, and many a reader may not easily reach the interpretation that the author intends. For that reason, while I sympathize with Edwin's view as to which definition of "drew on" is more likely to have been intended in each of the two examples given here, I wouldn't as a reader feel altogether confident of their matching the author's intention in a particular instance.

Meanwhile, as a writer, I would be quite uneasy about using "drew on" in the sense of "gradually passed," unless the context made my meaning unmistakable. This is especially so given that such alternatives as "gradually passed," "lingered," "grew older," and "dragged on" are available.

I suspect (without knowing) that in written English the "approached" sense of "drew on" is much more frequent than the "gradually passed" sense,* so I would be less inclined to change "night drew on" to "night approached" if that's the meaning I intended. Still, once you're conscious of a potential ambiguity resulting from competing definitions of a word, you may be less inclined to rely on that word to convey your meaning.

---

*As of the fourth edition of *The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language* (2000), the only definition of "draw on" that the AHDEL offered was this one:

> **draw on** To approach: *as evening draws on*.

This circumstance suggests that the "pass gradually" definition in *The American Heritage Dictionary of Phrasal Verbs* (2005), which Edwin Ashworth cites and links to in a comment beneath Centaurus's answer, is a fairly recently acknowledged sense of the phrase.

Answer (score -1):

As an intransitive verb, "draw on" means approach, so "The storm lessened as the night approached." should be the meaning.

> - draw on (intransitive verb) "approach" [Merriam-Webster](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/224233/confusions-about-the-definitions-of-draw-on)
> - "Night draws on and we must find a shelter."

As a transitive verb, "draw on" has a different meaning, though.

> - His novels draw heavily on his childhood. [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/draw-on-sth)

Comment: Ok, I just edited  in a photo in case you have any doubt about the other definition.

Comment: @Doeser  Would you give the reference?

Comment: It is in the question

Comment: @Doeser I can't find it here http://www.thefreedictionary.com/draw+on    Can you give me the link to your reference?

Comment: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/draw+on

Comment: **Draw on**: v. ...

3. To approach: The lost campers became more worried as nighttime drew on.
4. To pass gradually: The storm gradually lessened as the night drew on.

[The American Heritage® Dictionary of Phrasal Verbs. Copyright © 2005 by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. Published by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. All rights reserved.](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/draw+on).